# how to convert if-else with multiple condition with design pattern C#

Tags: design-patterns

i am aware of how to to convert if-else with single conditions in each if with design pattern.
but now i am little bit confuse because in my code there are multiple condition separated by && operator in if.
now how to refactor such type of cases.

code is as per below:

```
    public ActionResult PaymentDetails(PaymentlistingDTOVM model, string SearchButton)
    {
        PaymentlistingDTOVM dto = new PaymentlistingDTOVM();

        if (model.PaymentSearch == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Message", "Please select type to search ( Member No / Member Name).");
        }
        else if (model.PaymentSearch == "1" && model.Memberno == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Message", "Please Enter Member No.");
        }
        else if (model.PaymentSearch == "2" && model.MemberName == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Message", "Please Enter Member Name.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SearchButton) || model.Page.HasValue)
            {
                if (model.Memberno != null)
                {
                    var Listpay = objIPaymentlisting.AllPaymentDetails(Convert.ToString(model.Memberno));

                    var results = Listpay.Where(p => (p.MemberID == model.Memberno));

                    var pageIndex = model.Page ?? 1;

                    model.SearchResults = results.ToPagedList(pageIndex, RecordsPerPage);
                }
                else if (model.MemberName != null)
                {
                    string[] Memno = model.MemberName.Split('|');

                    var Listpay = objIPaymentlisting.AllPaymentDetails(Convert.ToString(Memno[3]));

                    var results = Listpay.Where(p => (p.MemberID == Convert.ToInt32(Memno[3])));

                    var pageIndex = model.Page ?? 1;

                    model.SearchResults = results.ToPagedList(pageIndex, RecordsPerPage);
                }
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `ICondition` interface that accepts the `PaymentlistingDTOVM` instance as the following

```
public interface ICondition<T>
{
   bool IsSatisfied(T obj);
}
```

And then you can create an implementation for each case. Of course since the implementations are going to be very small, you can create a common implementation such as this:

```
public class FuncBasedCondition<T> : ICondition<T>
{
   private readonly Func<T, bool> predicate;

   public FuncBasedCondition(Func<T, bool> predicate)
   {
       this.predicate = predicate;
   }

   //For C# 6, expression-bodied members can be used like this
   //public bool IsSatisfied(T obj) => predicate(obj);
   public bool IsSatisfied(T obj)
   {
       return predicate(obj);
   }
}
```

For example, to create an instance for the first condition, you create an instance of the condition class as the following:

```
new FuncBasedCondition<PaymentlistingDTOVM>(model => model.PaymentSearch == null);
```

Then, adjust your controller (or wherever the code your have shown exists) to accept different references to the different conditions that you need to handle.

Comment: Compilation error (line 53, col 30): ; expected
Compilation error (line 53, col 32): Method must have a return type
Compilation error (line 53, col 45): Identifier expected

Comment: error is comming in below statement:                                                    public bool IsSatisfied(T obj) => predicate(obj);                                                  Error:                                                                                                              Compilation error (line 53, col 30): ; expected
Compilation error (line 53, col 32): Method must have a return type
Compilation error (line 53, col 45): Identifier expected

Comment: This is a feature in C# 6 (Expression-bodied members). In case you're using a lesser version, the you can change it to the ordinary method body.